# Is there code folding support for C++ in Monodevelop?

Tags: c++, macos, monodevelop, folding

Is there any code folding support for C++ under Monodevelop (in Mac OS X)? It works with C# but I don't see it with C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is code folding support for C++ in Monodevelop, but it uses the ctags parser. If you install ctags, Monodevelop should enable the feature automatically. [[Reference](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td2272423)]